# How do I force a number to 10 decimal places in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have latitude and longitude values in my database out to 10 decimal places:

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | lat           | lng             |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 55 | 34.4208305000 | -119.6981901000 |
| 56 | 30.2671530000 |  -97.7430608000 |
```

I need to query the db for a match, but my current variable is a float with only 6 decimal places:

```
self.lat => 30.267153
```

How can I convert my float to have the extra decimal places so I get a match?

```
myloc = Marker.where("lat = ?", self.lat)
```

I've seen Decimal and BigDecimal docs.  Are those the best approach?

Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/)—or it's simpler brother [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001127)—to format your floating point number as a string with 10 decimals:

```
f = 30.267153
s = "%0.10f" % f
#=> "30.2671530000"
```

This seems fishy to me, though; what types of fields are your lat and lng columns? What RDBMS are you using? Do you really want to be comparing floating point values exactly? Do you really want to be storing them as strings?

Comment: Cool - that worked - thanks.  It's mysql.  The lat/lng fields are defined as type decimal(15,10).  This is a special case to check for a duplicate location before storing a new marker so I don't wind up with markers on top of each other - thus the exact comparison.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Phrogz's point was that it's generally unwise to compare floating point values for equality.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I get it now.  I'll ponder that and do some testing.

Answer (score 7):

you can try this:

```
"%.10f" % self.lat
```